# histogram/value counts from pandas dataframe columns with categorical data and custom "bins"

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, categorical-data

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([[ 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'b'], ['d', 'c']])
print(x)

   0  1
0  a  b
1  a  c
2  c  b
3  d  c
```

I would like to obtain the relative frequencies of the data in each column of the dataframe based on some custom "bins" which would be (a possible super-set of) the unique data values.  For example, if:

```
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I would like to obtain:

```
   0  1
a  2  0
b  0  2
c  1  2
d  1  0
e  0  0
f  0  0
```

Is there a one (or two) liner to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas-dataframe-value-counts), then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) based on b:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'b'], ['d', 'c']])

b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df = x.apply(lambda s: s.value_counts()).reindex(b).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   0  1
a  2  0
b  0  2
c  1  2
d  1  0
e  0  0
f  0  0
```

---

A [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) option:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'b'], ['d', 'c']])

b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
df = x.melt()
df = pd.crosstab(df['value'], df['variable']) \
    .reindex(b).fillna(0).astype(int) \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=0)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   0  1
a  2  0
b  0  2
c  1  2
d  1  0
e  0  0
f  0  0
```

Comment: First approach seems more intuitive to me.